# How did you get the warning popup implemented for identification questions?

Tags: support, close-reasons, asking-questions

How did you get the warning popup implemented for identification questions when user asks a question? We want a similar thing for autograph identification questions on [Sports SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/).

[This meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Buing-support-for-identification-questions) doesn't seem to mention it.

[image: popup]

Comment: Well, did you ask on [meta.sports.se] yet? It depends a little, since there are actually *two* different popups, one for tags and one for titles.

Comment: @Napoleon, [just did it](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/888/add-a-template-close-reason-for-autograph-identification-requests). So is it something that diamond mods can do by themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually ***two* different popups** (both existed even before banning identification questions, just that they were both warnings, now one is an error).

1. There is one popping up when you add certain tags (like e.g. [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie)). This one is now a hard error, not letting you add the tag at all. This is the older one. It was originally proposed on this site [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1419/49), I think. But it might not have ever been considered if this wasn't already a thing on SO for some tags.
2. Then there is one for titles containing specific keywords (I think currently just "movie"? But I'm not entirely sure). This one is just a warning, of course. I don't think there ever was much of a specific request for it. Some day Shog9 just...added it? Though, the nearest thing to it might be [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/49).

Both those things however are things that even the **per-site moderators cannot add (or update)** on their own. They have to be implemented by SE employees. However, as with all such things the usual way to get them implemented is **issuing a `feature-request` on the respective site's meta**, gathering some traction for it and fleshing out the details, and then getting the local mods to ask SE to put it into action.